# how to save in ctx and use it again in action method in telegraf js?

Tags: node.js, telegram-bot, telegraf

I am creating telegram bot with telegraf js and node js and I wanna pass data in state

```
const { Telegraf } = require("telegraf");

const bot = new Telegraf(API_KEY);

bot.command("start", (ctx, next) => {
  ctx.state.id= 10000;
  ctx.reply("you used bot", {
    reply_markup: {
      inline_keyboard: [[{ text: "hello", callback_data: "hello" }]],
    },
  });
  next(ctx);
});
```

but it doesn't appear in action method

```
bot.action("hello", (ctx) => {
  console.log(ctx.state);
});
```

this is the output of the console for `ctx.state`

```
{}
```

I passed data with start method and it succeeded but it doesn't work with action method

Comment: if you send the inline keyboard to user, I recommend to use bot.on("callback_query", (ctx) =>{ const selectedInlineQuery = ctx.callbackQuery.data;  } for getting the selected keyboard

Answer (score 1):

**State** is not persistent storage for your data. It would available in terms of one execution chain and usually used to share info between middlewares.

If you want to store something, like `id` in your example, you better use **Session**(`ctx.session`), here is simple session bot example on typescript: https://github.com/feathers-studio/telegraf-docs/blob/master/examples/session-bot.ts

☝️ However, session might be tricky, because by default it is also not persistent and might be collapsed while execution. That's why I would recommend to **store** data either in a **`const`** or in a **database**.